openpyxl.chart is creating a new series for each row
I have a simple python script to create an excel spreadsheet with a line chart and single series of data. The data in the spreadsheet is as desired. When opened in MS Excel, the chart contains a separate series for each row in the table. The chart looks fine when opened with Numbers app.
    from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference

    rows = [
        ['Date', 'Force'],
        [date(2015,9, 1), 4],
        [date(2015,9, 2), 9],
        [date(2015,9, 3), 11]
    ]

    for row in rows:
        ws.append(row) # Add each row to the worksheet

    chart = LineChart()
    chart.title = "Force Measurements"
    chart.y_axis.title = "Force (LBS)"
    chart.x_axis.title = "Date"
    data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2,max_row=4) 
    chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    ws.add_chart(chart, "D5")

The chart worksheet created in Excel ends up with four series:

But should be just one series like this:

I have tried to use Series with no effect. I don't know if this is a bug in Excel or an issue with openpyxl. Anything that can be done in code to fix this in MS Excel?

The chart doesn't seem the code you supplied, but in any case you should be using (min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=4)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78865708/openpyxl-auto-assigns-colors-to-charts-categories/78866080#78866080

That is the answer: chart.varyColors=False   @AxelRichter

Axel, reducing the data set to a single column causes Openpyxl to create 4 series and no a-axis. This would be clearer in a bar chart.
